# showing $f(x_1,x_2)=\sqrt[3]{x_1x_2}$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Given $f\colon\mathbb R^{>0}\times\mathbb R^{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb R, (x_1,x_2)\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x_1\cdot x_2}$ I want to prove that $f$ is differentiable.

I know $f$ is partial differentiable and all partial derivatives are continuous, so $f$ is differentiable.

But I am wondering if I could show it by the definition of differentiability.

E.g. consider the point $1=(1,1)$. So there has to be a linear map $A$ such  that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)-Ah}{\|h\|}=0$

Let $h=(h_1,h_2)$. It's $A=(\frac13,\frac13)$ and so $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(1+h_1)(1+h_2)}-1-\frac13h_1-\frac13h_2}{\|h\|}=0$ ?

I know how to show it using polar coordinates but is there any way by doing it without any big 'help functions/relations' etc.?

Comment: Maybe prove $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ is differentiable first? The algebra is not too different as Ma Ming's post should start to show you... the key idea is the difference of cubes formula. Also, if you're asking this question the big O notation is worth learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint $\sqrt[3]{1+h_1}-1-\frac{h_1}{3}=O(h_1^2)$, then 
$$\sqrt[3]{1+h_1}\sqrt[3]{1+h_2}=(1+\frac{h_1}{3}+O(h_1^2))(1+\frac{h_2}{3}+O(h_1^2）)=1+\frac{h_1}{3}+\frac{h_2}{3}+O(h_1^2)+O(h_2^2).$$

To show $\sqrt[3]{1+h_1}-1-\frac{h_1}{3}=O(h_1^2)$, you may use the formula $a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$.